# ASP.NET MVC/IIS 7: Creating dynamic websites (subdomains) with a button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm working on a community forum script, and I want to give every one an opportunity to create their own community forum for free.

So let's say I have the following domain:

www.forum.com

Bob wants to create his forum, he signs up, picks a username ("bob") and gets his own forum instantly: bob.forum.com

There are the things that need to be created automatically:

- New subdomain
- New IIS site
- New database

And I want to use the same script (bin dll and .aspx files). Of course I'd like to update them instantly because if I have 100 subforums, that would be pain in the butt to update all 100 scripts manually.

I know this is a pretty hard thing to do, but I really, **really** need this.

If you know an article about it, please post a link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or do you just need one IIS website which tackles this through url rewriting, saving you the headache and security hole of having a web process capable of monkeying around with itself?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. I asked a question on ServerFault:

http://serverfault.com/questions/170755/iis-7-redirecting-from-non-existing-subdomains-to-a-subfolder